# Can't Loop Through XML Elements Using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to loop through an XML document and get out the details of each item.

I manage to get into a single item like this and print its values:

```
   foreach($xml->children() as $games){
        echo $games->item->title;
    }
```

But it doesn't loop through all the values.
My instinct to loop through says it should look something like this:

```
foreach($xml->children()->item as $games){
    echo $games->title;
}
```

But this doesn't return anything.

Example of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <channel>
        <title>feed EUR</title>
        <link>https://www.google.com/</link>
        <description>Lorem ipsum</description>
        <item>
                <g:id>99f3a672-c54a-11e8-83c9-186590d66063</g:id>
                <title>7 Days to Die Steam Key GLOBAL</title>
            </item>
        <item>
                <g:id>9aacf9ec-c54a-11e8-9925-186590d66063</g:id>
                <title>A Hat in Time Steam Key GLOBAL</title>
            </item>
        <item>
```

Comment: `foreach($xml->channel as $channel){ echo $channel->title; }`

Comment: hmm yeah, I was ignoring the channel element. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Children of root `<rss>` node are `<channel>`, so you can iterate over them:

```
foreach ($xml->channel as $channel) {
    echo ($channel->title);
}
```